# Error initializing SparkContext when using SPARK-SHELL in spark standalone

Tags: apache-spark

I have Installed Scala.

I have installed java 8.

Also all environment variables has been set for spark,java and Hadoop.

Still getting this error while running spark-shell command. Please someone help....google it a lot but didn't find anything.

[spark-shell error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Thmyd.jpg)
[spark shell error2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d7eAz.jpg)

Comment: You should paste the relevant part of the error as text https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question

Answer (score 0):

Spark’s shell provides a simple way to learn the API, Start shell  by running the following in the Spark directory:

```
./bin/spark-shell
```

Then run below scala code snippet:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
val logFile = "YOUR_SPARK_HOME/README.md" // Should be some file on your system
val spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("Simple Application").getOrCreate()
val logData = spark.read.textFile(logFile).cache()
val numAs = logData.filter(line => line.contains("a")).count()
val numBs = logData.filter(line => line.contains("b")).count()
println(s"Lines with a: $numAs, Lines with b: $numBs")
```

If stills error persist,then we have to look into environment set up

Comment: Error:not found value spark

Comment: @VibhorGupta edited my  answer, try out let me know progress